# Problem with useInterval and react hooks - infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, react-hooks, intervals

I have a dice component, and i want it to spit random values n times, and after that show a static value, and this should happen each time props is updated. so i used setInterval in the following code:

```
  //iter - keep count on how many times we rendered a value
  const [iter, setIter] = useState(0);

  //keep the intervalId given throughout the renderes
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(undefined);

  //check each render(iter update) if iter has reached 0, to clear the interval
  useEffect(() => {
    if (iter <= 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, [iter]);

  //if the props updated, call roll dice
  useEffect(() => {
    rollDice();
  }, [props]);

  const rollDice = () => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      //reduce iter every 100ms
      setIter((prev) => prev - 1);
    }, 100);

    //run this interval 10 times
    setIter(10);
    setIntervalId(interval);
  };
```

This is what the component returns:

```
 {props.values.map((val, i) => (
    <FontAwesomeIcon
      key={i}
      //randomize icons
      icon={dice[iter ? Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) : val - 1]}
      size={props.size || "4x"}
      color={props.color || "white"}
    />
  ))}
```

But for some reason i get an infinite loop, the first useEffect keeps firing.
Why does this happen and how can i avoid this kind of a bug in the future?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because you are using state for storing local variables. You call `setIter` to update `iter`, but `setIter` is asynchronous. So it won't update immediately which means that `iter` might skip 0 and go into negatives numbers which will be infinite if you just check if `iter` is different than 0. But of course it will work (sort of) if you check that `iter` is greater than 0.

You should replace your `iter` state with a ref:

```
const iter = useRef(0);
```

Then you can update iter by using its current value:

```
iter.current = 10;
iter.current--;
```

Then your icon code will be:

```
icon={dice[iter.current ? Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) : val - 1]}
```

Likewise, intervalId should not be stored in state but in a ref:

```
const intervalId = useRef();
```

Comment: I'm now storing the itevalId in a ref, but i cant store iter in a ref, because i need the component to render each time iter updates.
And i have only now noticed that the infinite loop continues, but the render output  stays the same. But thank you for the ref suggestion

Comment: That's the thing, the component will not render each time state `iter` updates, because `iter` won't update every time you call `setIter`. Not only that but there is no guarantee that your interval function will be called 10 times. If you really want 10 times, the only way is by using a ref. But you can have another state that you update at the same time, and this one will be used for rendering

Comment: Thank you, it worked, this is what i did: https://pastebin.com/MEjhUuwT , If this is not what you meant then pleas clarify what i did wrong, But anyway It all makes sense now, Thank you :)